# Optimizing the condition number

Tags: computational-complexity, linear-algebra, algorithms, matrix-analysis

Suppose I have a set $S$ of $N$ vectors in $W=\mathbb{R}^m,$ with $N \gg m.$ I want to choose a subset $\{v_1, \dots, v_m\}$ of $S$ in such a way that the condition number of the matrix with columns $v_1, \dotsc, v_m$ is as small as possible -- notice that this is trivial if $S$ does not span $W,$ since the condition number is always $\infty,$ so we can assume that $S$ does span. The question is: is there a better algorithm than the obvious $O(N^{m+c})$ algorithm (where we look at all the $m$-element subsets of $S?$). and how much better? One might guess that there is an algorithm polynomial in the input size, but none jumps to mind.

Comment: I don't know of anything theoretically better.  Something that should work in practice is to do Gram Schmidt orthogonalization: when you choose the largest m/2 vectors and orthogonalize the rest, it makes sense to choose the longer of the remaining processed vectors to reach your goal.  That should prune a lot of the search space.  (I am assuming condition number is related to determinant.)  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2012.08.15

Comment: @Igor: The condition number of any matrix is always $\ge 1$, using a consistent norm, so am I misreading your question (because you say "...condition number is always 0...$)?

Comment: @Igor: given Suvrit's remark, maybe you were thinking about the reverse condition number when writing? Typically people want to get small condition numbers, not large ones.

Comment: sorry, I meant "inverse of the condition number", not "reverse".

Comment: @Federico and @Suvrit: of course you are right, I want SMALL condition numbers. Will fix.

Comment: OK, this is now fixed.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*Update*: [This recent paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1509.00748) on this topic may also be of interest; it's quite short and claims to have a fully constructive approach.

---

I think the closest to answering your question is the following paper.

"Column subset selection, matrix factorization, and eigenvalue optimization", by J. A. Tropp.
*In Proc. 2009 ACM-SIAM Symp. Discrete Algorithms (SODA), pp. 978-986, New York, NY, Jan. 2009.*  [SODA .pdf](http://users.cms.caltech.edu/%7Ejtropp/conf/Tro09-Column-Subset-SODA.pdf) or a [longer arXiv version](https://arxiv.org/abs/0806.4404).

From the abstract:

> Most research from the algorithms and numerical linear algebra communities focuses on a variant called rank-revealing QR, which seeks a well-conditioned collection of columns that spans the (numerical) range of the matrix.
>
> ....
>
> a celebrated result of Bourgain and Tzafriri demonstrates that each matrix with normalized columns contains a large column submatrix that is exceptionally well conditioned. Unfortunately, standard proofs of this result cannot be regarded as algorithmic. This paper presents a randomized, polynomial-time algorithm that produces the submatrix promised by Bourgain and Tzafriri.

Comment: This is VERY close to what I am looking for, thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I have been working recently on a similar problem, namely, maximizing the absolute value of the determinant of a chosen $m\times m$ submatrix $S$ of a $m\times N$ submatrix $V$ (think to the columns of $V$ as your vectors). At first sight, it may seem that the two problems are not related, but one can prove that if $S$ has this property then $S^{-1}V$ has all entries bounded in modulus by 1. This is enough to ensure some form of stability, at least in the applications that we were [investigating](http://opus4.kobv.de/opus4-matheon/frontdoor/index/index/docId/906), and I suspect that yours case might be similar. Other useful references are [this paper](http://spring.inm.ras.ru/osel/?p=13) and [this one](https://math.berkeley.edu/~mgu/MA273/Strong_RRQR.pdf).

I can tell you the following.

- Finding the maximum volume submatrix is an [NP-hard problem](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s00453-011-9582-6), so I guess that your problem may suffer the same fate
- a useful relaxation, however, is finding a submatrix that has *locally* maximum volume, i.e., larger than all those that can be obtained by changing one vector only. There is a [paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1080/03081088508817636) by Knuth (yes, *that* Knuth) that studies the problem.
- a second relaxation is finding a submatrix $S$ such that $S^{-1}V$ has all entries bounded by some real $\tau>1$. This problem can be solved explicitly in $O(Nm^2\frac{\log m}{\log\tau})$. The good conditioning properties carry over to this relaxation, up to a factor $\tau$. Putting everything together, I think that one can prove using the techniques in our paper that the matrix chosen by the algorithm has conditioning which differs by at most a factor $O(\sqrt{Nm}\tau)$ from the conditioning of the rectangular matrix $V$ (defined as largest over smallest singular value), which is a theoretical maximum for the conditioning of $S$ (I think).
- if you have a practical computation and you want to check how things work with this solution, I have some [Matlab code](https://bitbucket.org/fph/pgdoubling/overview) in a packaged and usable state that you might wish to try out. Feel free to ask for explanation if the documentation is too poor.

Comment: Thanks much! I will certainly check out the references and the code -- it does sound very relevant [not exactly clear what the precise connection is, but...]