# Finding a sub-matrix from a fat matrix with the best condition number.

Tags: combinatorial-optimization

Given a m-by-n matrix with $n>>m$ and with a known rank of $k\leq m$, what would be a computationally effective way of finding out $k$ columns, such that the matrix formed using these $k$ columns has the best condition number?

Comment: Something to consider: Use some heuristic to select one or two columns, and then do Gram Schmidt orthonormalization to guess the best candidates for the rest.  Gerhard "Ask Me About Dumb Guessing" Paseman, 2013.04.26

Comment: seems to be a duplicate of: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/104803/optimizing-the-condition-number/104858

Answer (score 1):

Finding this subset of columns is a non-trivial task, but some approximate answers are known. For details and pointers, please refer [to my answer here.](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/104803/optimizing-the-condition-number/104858#104858)